# How to pass limit into another class with switch?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I want to pass in choice (derived from same class) and then pass limit to another class that will use the limit.  I'm getting errors on the below.

```
    public int ProcessChoice(int choice)
    {
        int limit;

        switch(limit)
        {
        case 1: limit = 10;
        HiLow thegame = new HiLow(limit);
        break;
        case 2: limit = 50;
        HiLow thegame = new HiLow(limit);
        break;
        case 3: limit = 100;
        HiLow thegame = new HiLow(limit);
        break;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? And looks like you want to switch(choice) not switch(limit)

Comment: `limit` is not initialized in your code.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a possible typo in your code.  Notice that the first two lines in your method are

```
int limit;
switch(limit)
{ ... }
```

When you switch on limit, it hasn't been initialized yet!  The C# language does the sane thing and disallows using variables before they are initialized, so the compiler rightly refuses to compile this code.

Of course, the fix for this compilation error is to change the first two lines of the method to

```
int limit;
switch (choice)
{ ... }
```

Comment: Good catch, I didn't see that

Comment: Thanks, I made that change.  Getting "Error 1 A local variable named 'thegame' is already defined in this scope"

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the constructor to `HiLow` takes an `int` parameter, like this:

```
public class HiLow
{
    ...
    public HiLow(int limit)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```